# jQuery stopPropagation not stopping click through

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I have a panzoom plugin that is working well. When I click on `var elem` it adds a small div `cp_select` in the correct location. Then, when I click on that newly created `cp_select` div, it removes that div. So you can add and remove it accordingly. However, when I click on the `cp_select` div, it removes it then immediately adds it back in because the click is propagating through. I have tried event.stopPropagation() and event.stopImmediatePropagation() with no luck. Any ideas how to prevent the `cp_select` firing the `map_click(e)`?

[image]

```
window.panzoom = panzoom(elem, {
        onClick(e)     {
            map_click(e);
        }
})


function map_click(e) {
    
    $(".map_cont").prepend('<div class="cp_select" style="left:'+calc_x+'px ;top:'+calc_y+'px"></div>');

}


 $('body').on('click', '.cp_select', function(event) {
    
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    $(this).remove()
    return false;
    
});
```

Comment: Well you are capturing the click on the body....

Comment: That is b/c the .cp_select is created dynamically. Is there a better way?

Comment: check the event object inside the click and see what you are clicking. Maybe `e.target` will tell you what was clicked. (Never used this thing...)

Comment: I suspect it is due to the order of callback calls. Could you test moving "$('body').on('click',..." part above "window.panzoom = panzoom(elem, {" part? If it works, I'll try to explain what I think.

Comment: Just tried moving  the "$('body').on('click',..." to the top - no luck :(

Comment: Look at the target like I suggested.

Comment: Just remembered, there is no control over the execution order of the event callbacks. I'll wrap up an answer and suggest another approach.

Answer (score -1):

The problem must be specifically with however panzoom is dealing with its onClick, or otherwise in code not shown in the question; if I substitute a plain click event handler on the window in place of your panzoom call, `event.stopPropagation()` works as expected.

```js
// nonessential code removed and simplified for demo

function map_click() {
  $(".map_cont").prepend('<div class="cp_select"></div>');
}

$('body').on('click', '.cp_select', function(event) {
  $(this).remove();
  event.stopPropagation();
});


window.onclick = map_click // stand-in for your panzoom function
```

```css
.cp_select {
  border: 3px solid;
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(click anywhere)
<div class="map_cont"></div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you Daniel